# Linked List using nodes to intake characters

Tags: java, linked-list, character, nodes

So, I am trying to figure out how to do the following for a homework assignment: Please write a program that asks the user for one letter. Insert the letter at the end of a linked list and print out the linked list. Ask for another letter and insert at the end of the linked list and print out the list. Continue until the user states they have no more letters to input. Then, build another link list that will ask the user for a letter, one at a time, and then insert it to the list in alphabetical order. After each insertion, print out the list and continue until the user is done inputting letters.

This is what I have so far, and where I have been stuck for about a week now...

import TerminalIO.*;

public class LinkedLists {

```
public static void addLine(){
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String answer = "y";
    String n = null;
    char nodePointer = ' ';
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();

    Node start = new Node();
    Node temp = new Node();

    do{
        System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
        nodePointer = reader.readChar();
        start.letter = nodePointer;

        start.nodeptr = new Node(start.letter);
        //start.nodeptr.letter = temp.letter;
        start = start.nodeptr;

        System.out.print("Linked list: ");

        temp = start;
        while(temp != null){
            System.out.print(start.letter);
            temp = temp.nodeptr;
        }
        addLine();

        System.out.print("Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? ");
        n = reader.readLine();

        addLine();
    }while(answer.compareTo(n) == 0);

}
```

}

**Constructor:**

public class Node {

```
char letter;
Node nodeptr;

Node(){
    letter = ' ';
    nodeptr = null;
}

Node(char x){
    letter = x;
    nodeptr = null;
}

Node(char x, Node y){
    letter = x;
    nodeptr = y;
}
```

}

**The output I get for this is:**

Enter a letter: m
Linked list: m
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: o
Linked list: o
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? n

This goes on for whatever letter I input, since the letter I input is the same letter that comes out in its own list...

What it should output (1st part):

Enter a letter: m
Linked list: m
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: o
Linked list: mo
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: n
Linked list: mon
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: e
Linked list: mone
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: y
Linked list: money
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Then for the second part of the program, it should output in alphabetical order like so:

Enter a letter: m
Linked list: m
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: o
Linked list: mo
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: n
Linked list: mno
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: e
Linked list: emno
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

Enter a letter: y
Linked list: emnoy
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y

If anyone can help point me in the right direction or write the code, either would be beneficial, because I am honestly lost right now as to how I am supposed to manipulate the nodes to do what I want them to do.

Comment: Tell us more about the output you're getting.  That will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Fixed the output. Thanks Isaac for telling me about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are missing part of your code that defines Node.  However, even without that, I can see your *start* pointer is getting reset inside your loop for EVERY entered letter via this line in your loop:

```
start = start.nodeptr;
```

That is not a proper way to do things.  A linked-list head (aka your *start* pointer) is only supposed to be set ONCE when the very first letter is added, then never changed on subsequent passes through your loop.

Also, in this code segment:

```
temp = start;
while(temp != null){
    System.out.print(start.letter);
    temp = temp.nodeptr;
}
```

You are looping on *temp*, but always printing out *start.letter*.

If I was going to adapt your code, you should build each new letter into your *temp* pointer, and only set *start* = *temp* when *start* is NULL.  And you should also maintain a linked list tail (aka a *last* pointer) for quick insertion of the next letter to the end of the linked list.

So I would adapt your code as follows, though since I do not have your Node definition there could be some errors in the below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String answer = "y";
    String n = null;
    char nodePointer = ' ';
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();

    Node start = NULL;
    Node last = NULL;
    Node temp = NULL;

    do{
        System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
        nodePointer = reader.readChar();

        temp = new Node(nodePointer);
        temp.nodeptr = NULL;
        if (start == NULL) start = temp;
        if (last != NULL) last.nodeptr = temp;
        last = temp;

        System.out.print("Linked list: ");

        temp = start;
        while(temp != null){
            System.out.print(temp.letter);
            temp = temp.nodeptr;
        }
        addLine();

        System.out.print("Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? ");
        n = reader.readLine();

        addLine();
    }while(answer.compareTo(n) == 0);

}
```

I'm going to leave it up to you to work out the second part of your assignment ... when you must INSERT new letters alphabetically into the start, middle, or end of the linked list (rather than part 1 which is the trivial case of just adding the letters to the end of the list).  One Hint, there are existing StackOverflow answers on all this.  I've answered 3 or 4 on linked lists just this week.

Comment: Thanks cybermike! I honestly only searched on Google for answers to this kind of stuff but couldn't find anything that related directly to what I was needing to do.

Comment: As a FYI, check the "Related" column to the right of your question (and everyone else's question that you initially found via google search).  There are some relevant answers cited.

Comment: Yeah, this is my first time posting to Stack so I just figured I would post my own question.  Turns out there is a slight problem with the code you answered with, as it stops outputting the letters after m. So for example if I enter m, then o it will output mo.  Then when I enter n it outputs mn not mon.  Any quick fix for that?  And I am going to include the constructor for the nodes that I am using.

Comment: Oh indeed I had a error, which I fixed in the code posted above.  I forgot to set the *last* pointer to the new last entry after adjusting the former last entry to point to the new last entry.  I altered the two lines of code to make it proper and efficient.

Comment: Awesome thanks mike, I am going to figure out the second part of the program now!

Comment: Ok, I'm about as confused as could be... I've spent the last 4 days trying to figure the alphabetical part out but I just can't seem to grasp it.  Could you give me another hint?